# Way to "flatten" Rails migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I'm working on deploying my first Rails application right now, and somewhere along the way, I botched a migration. When I try to push my application to the production server and run `rake db:migrate`, it fails somewhere with an error.

Now, I am *way* too lazy to work through my migrations individually to find out what went wrong, so I'm trying to avoid doing that.  Given that my current development database works just fine, is there a way to "flatten" the current schema into a single, comprehensive migration?

I understand that this is sloppy, and I understand that I likely did a dumb thing to break the migration chain in the first place.  (I probably edited the database schema directly somewhere, which I now understand is a no-no.) This is a pretty small project though, and I'm essentially the only developer involved, so I'm comfortable sweeping this issue under the rug if possible.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks for lending your expertise.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is what the `db/schema.rb` file is for. If you've only got structural changes in your migrations you will be able to run `rake db:schema:load` rather than running `rake db:migrate` to get the absolute structure for your tables.

Comment: He might need to do a rake db:schema:dump prior to that if he's changed the db in the meantime.

Comment: Worked like a champ.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you edited the schema directly you will need to run:

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

This will take whatever is in the database and create a schema.rb file. Then you can run rake db:schema:load anytime you want. However it will mean that your migrations are still bad. You could delete all of them and recreate them from the schema.rb file.

Comment: Thanks Kyle! Yeah, I just deleted the old migrations and now I'm in business.